# PHP + MYSQL autocomplete - retornando ID

Tags: php, javascript, autocompletar

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para faculdade,
e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Tenho que buscar utilizado autocomplete passando como parâmetro o nome do medico, assim recuperar o **id** do mesmo e salvar no banco. Já tentei de todas as formas mas não consigo recuperar o **id**, apenas o autocomplete funciona.

Exemplo

No PHP

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Profissional</label>

    <input type="text" name="prof" value="" class="form-control"   placeholder="Insira o nome do Profissional." id="txtProf" class="typeahead">
    <input type="hidden" name="idprof" value="" class="form-control"  id="idprof" >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label >Procedimento</label>
    <input type="text" name="proced" value="" class="form-control"   placeholder="Insira o nome do Procedimento." id="txtProc" class="typeahead">
</div>
```

No JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtProf').typeahead({
        source: function (query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../classes/db/server.php",
                data: 'query=' + query,            
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                  result($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return item;
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

E no arquivo de busca (server.php):

```
$keyword = strval($_POST['query']);
$search_param = "{$keyword}%";
$conn =new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'clinicanova');

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT pf.nome FROM tb_pessoa pf, tb_profissional prof
                         WHERE pf.id = prof.tb_pessoa_id
                         and prof.status = 'A'
                         and pf.nome LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$search_param);            
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $countryResult[] = $row["nome"];
    }
    echo json_encode($countryResult);

}
$conn->close();
```

Queria uma maneira de completar o campo ID com os dados que o usuário selecionar.

PRONTO CONSEGUI RESGATAR O ID SO FALTA POVOAR DENTRO DO HIDDEN sabe como consigo fazer isso porque adicionando direto no result nao funciona
, MEU JAVASCRIPT ESTA ASSIM AGORA:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtProf').typeahead({
        source: function (query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../classes/db/server.php",
                data: 'query=' + query,            
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
        result($.map(data, function (item) {
          return item.nome;
           $('#idprof').val(item.id);
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

COMO FAÇO PARA INSERIR ESSE "item.id" em um input

Comment: Primeiro você tem que recuperar e armazenar o ID na variável `countryResult`. Seu `select` está retornando apenas o `pf.nome`

Comment: desculpe a ignorancia, estou me habituando agora com a linguagem nao sei se fiz certo mais alterei o codigo para:   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $countryResult[] = $row["nome"];
                $countryResult[] = $row["id"];
  }

Comment: nao entendi como funciona essa logica, de passar e como recuperar la no js e trabalhar no formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para retornar os dados de `id` e `nome` do profissional, temos que informar na `query` sql esses campos. Ex:

```js
/* Aqui utilizarei uma lib do Typehead para auxiliar. Essa lib irá nos auxiliar com os requests */
var profissionais = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('nome'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  /* Aqui eu defino a URL do JSON e o termo. Nesse caso eu utilizarei GET e não POST */
  prefetch: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/fn5wb', /* Substitua APENAS "https://api.myjson.com/bins/fn5wb". */
  remote: {
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/fn5wb?query=%query', /* Substitua APENAS "https://api.myjson.com/bins/fn5wb". */
    'wildcard': '%query'
  }
});

$('#lista-profissionais .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'profissionais',
  display: 'nome',
  source: profissionais
});

/* Esse evento irá capturar o resultado do nome e ID */
$('#lista-profissionais .typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
  $("#idprof").val(suggestion.id);

  alert("Nome: " + suggestion.nome + "\nId: " + suggestion.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="lista-profissionais">
  <input type="hidden" name="idprof" value="" class="form-control" id="idprof">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Informe o nome do profissional">
</div>
```

**server.php**

```
$keyword = strval($_GET['query']);

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'clinicanova');

/* Aqui informamos que devemos capturar o ID e o NOME do profissional. */
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT pf.id AS `id`, pf.nome AS `nome` FROM tb_pessoa pf, tb_profissional prof
                         WHERE pf.id = prof.tb_pessoa_id
                         and prof.status = 'A'
                         and pf.nome LIKE ?");

$sql->bind_param("s", "{$keyword}%");            

$sql->execute();

$result = $sql->get_result();

$countryResult = [];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    /* Aqui montamos o array com os dados que serão exibidos */
    $countryResult[] = [
            "id" => $row["id"], //Verifique se esse index realmente existe.
            "nome" => $row["nome"], //Verifique se esse index realmente existe.
    ];
}

echo json_encode($countryResult);

$conn->close();
```

> Adicionei um json que não fosse do server.php para deixar funcional aqui no site, mas você deve alterar a URL para o server.php

Para testar o **server.php**, acesse **https://www.example.com/server.php?query=A**, caso esteja funcionando, verifique se a URL no `javascript` está correta.

Comment: amigo nao funcionou muito bem, nao carrega os dados!

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Adicionei algumas informações.

Comment: amigo realizei a modificação e não funciona, não sei se sou muito burro, pq teoricamente e pra ta certo mas na pagina nao carrega o autocomplete, conhece outra forma que possa utilizar esse autocomplete e resgatar pra um hidden o id do que o usuario escolher

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e posta seu "novo" código, como você está fazendo dessa vez. Já testou apenas o `server.php`?

Comment: atualizei a minha resposta, consegui resgatar   o ID gostaria de saber como setar ele num input agora

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, sera que daria para executar alguma função se caso o usuário não escolha nenhuma dos dados vindos do banco? Tipo, preciso que obrigatoriamente a informação tenha que vir do banco, não deixando o usuario digitar uma diferente

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Você pode adicionar uma validação no servidor. Caso o valor não seja encontrado no banco de dados, retorna um erro para o usuário.